# A comparison of two dates to update the database in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, date, swift3, swift4

I have this code:

```
func getSystemDate()-> String{
        let date = Date()
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let hour = String(format: "%02d",calendar.component(.hour, from: date))
        let minutes = String(format: "%02d",calendar.component(.minute, from: date))
        let seconds = String(format: "%02d",calendar.component(.second, from: date))

        let day = String(format: "%02d",calendar.component(.day, from: date))
        let month = String(format: "%02d",calendar.component(.month, from: date))
        let year = String(format: "%02d",calendar.component(.year, from: date))

        let fullDate = "\(year)-\(month)-\(day) \(hour):\(minutes):\(seconds)"

        return fullDate
    }
let date1 = getSystemDate()
let date2 = "2018-05-23 13:14:47"

if date1 > date2 {
    print("its ok - update available")
} else {
    print("wrong - you have actually database")
}
```

My function `getSystemDate()` returns actual date in String.
In variable `date2` - I have database update date.

I need to determine if it is possible to update the database and compare the current date with the date of the available database:...

How can I compare these dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Calendar` to compare two `Dates`. You can go to `second unit` also, if the difference is 0 means they are equal or else you can check which one is greater :

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
//dateFormatter.timeZone   = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")  // To add timezone

guard let dateOne = dateFormatter.date(from: "2018-05-23 13:14:47"), let dateTwo = dateFormatter.date(from: "2018-05-23 14:14:47") else {
    print("One of the date conversion is nil")
    return
}

print(dateOne, dateTwo)

let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.second], from: dateOne, to: dateTwo)
let secondsInBetween: Int = components.second!

print(secondsInBetween)
```

Comment: Ok, thanx. How can I convert my dates (I have them in the system in the string) to the Date format (to work with your code)?

Comment: Yes. I have in my function getSystemDate and in database - date in format String. Can you show me how can I compare 2 date in String format with yours code?

Comment: @triff Updated my answer.

Comment: It does not work correctly: https://image.ibb.co/bEwOho/Zrzut_ekranu_2018_06_06_o_12_06_26.png - The input and output dates are different

Comment: @triff I added timeZone line too, if you add that there will no diff in input and output date but that doesn't matter for your operation as both dates are giving UTC output. What you want is if dateOne > dateTwo, dateOne < dateTwo and dateOne = dateTwo. 

Positive difference means dateOne is smaller than dateTwo and negative means dateOne is greater that dateTwo, 0 means they are equal. 

Also dateFormat has a typo : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", it should be capital MM for month.